# How to exclude a property in WebAPI on demand

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-web-api

I am new to WebApi, so please excuse if the question is amateurish: I use AngularJS's "$resource" to communicate with the WebApi-Controller "BondController". This works great.
My problem: The entity "Bond" has a reference to a list of entity "Price":

```
public class Bond
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual List<Price> Prices { get; set; }
}
```

What I am looking for is a way to **exclude the nested list "Prices"** such as

```
[JsonIgnore]
```

**BUT, in some other situation, I still need a way to retrieve Bonds including this nested list,** e.g. via a second controller "Bond2".

What can I do?

Will I need some ViewModel on top of the entity Bond? 
Can I somehow exclude the List of Prices in the controller itself:

```
public IQueryable<Bond> GetBonds()
{
     return db.Bonds [ + *some Linq-Magic that excludes the list of Prices*]
}
```

Background: the list of Prices might become rather long and the Get-Requests would easily become > 1MB. In most cases, the prices don't even need to be displayed to the user, so I'd like to exclude them from the response. But in one case, they do... Thank you for your input!

**EDIT:**
I see that, for some sort of Linq Magic, I would need a new type "PricelessBond"

**EDIT2**
Found a nice example of using DTO [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/create-a-rest-api-with-attribute-routing) and will use that.

The solution is to create a non-persistent BondDTO class that acts as a "shell" and that has only those properties you desire to be visible in a certain use-case and then, in the BondDTOController,  transform the selection of Bond => BondDTO via means of a Linq Lambda Select expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am no expert in WebApi but it seems that you have more than one problem.
Why won't you create a class hierarchy?

```
public class PricelessBond // :)
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
}

public class Bond : PricelessBond
{
    public List<Price> Prices {get; set;}
}
```

Then you can expose data via two different methods:

```
public class BondsController : ApiController
{
    [Route("api/bonds/get-bond-without-price/{id}")]
    public PricelessBond GetBondWithoutPrice(int id)
    {
        return DataAccess.GetBondWithoutPrice(id);
    }

    [Route("api/bonds/get-bond/{id}")]
    public Bond GetBond()
    {
        return DataAccess.GetBond(id);
    }
}
```

And in your `DataAccess` class:

```
public class DataAccess
{
    public PricelessBond GetBondWithoutPrice(int id)
    {
        return db.Bonds
            .Select(b => new PricelessBond
            {
                ID = b.ID
            })
            .Single(b => b.ID == id);
    }

    public Bond GetBond(int id)
    {
        return db.Bonds
            .Select(b => new Bond
            {
                ID = b.ID,
                Prices = b.Prices.Select(p => new Price{}).ToArray()
            })
            .Single(b => b.ID == id);
    }
}
```

Of course, having two data access methods implies some code overhead but since you say the response could get greater than 1MB this also means that you should spare your database server and not fetch data that you don't need.

So, in your data access layer load only required data for each operation.

I have tested this in a scratch project and it worked.

Comment: Hmm do I understand your idea correct: i should instantiate bonds as Bond, use two controllers (BondController & PricelessBondController) and, when I need the PricelessBond, cast?

Comment: Hmm the more I think about your answer, the less I get it :o)